# Couldn't match type `[]' with `IO' Expected: IO (IO ()) Actual: [IO ()]

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell.

```
showAllContent file = do 
  content <- readFile file
  let splittedContent = splitOn "\n" content
  [beautyPrint x | x <- splittedContent]

beautyPrint line = do
    putStrLn line
```

I want to transform the strings before I print, but I get the error

> ```
> Couldn't match type "[]" with "IO"
>     Expected: IO (IO ())
>     Actual: [IO ()]
> ```

Comment: use `mapM_ beautyPrint splittedContent` as last line of the `showAllContent` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this part of the error

> `Expected: IO (IO ()) Actual: [IO ()]`

It is telling you that you have wrapped something of type `IO ()` into a list, thus obtaining a `[IO ()]`, instead of into a `IO`, which would result in the desired `IO (IO ())`.

After all, when you do `[beautyPrint x | x <- splittedContent]` you are "extracting" the content out of `splittedContent`, executing `beautyPring` on it, but then you're wrapping it in a list with `[]`, rather than in the `IO` monad.

Now with `return` you could wrap *one* thing in the `IO` monad, but you have more than one thing (that's why you're using the list comprehension), you have a list of things each coming from the corresponding `beautyPrint x`.

So how can you wrap *them all* in a `IO`? `sequence` comes helping us. Look at its signature:

```hs
sequence :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => t (m a) -> m (t a)
```

which for the specific case of the `IO` `Monad` and the list (`[]`) `Traversable`, is

```hs
sequence :: [IO ()] -> IO [()]
```

So you can do

```hs
sequence [beautyPrint x | x <- splittedContent]
```

Then, since you know you're executing `beautyPrint` on every element of the list, you can easily rewrite that as

```hs
sequence $ map beautyPrint [x | x <- splittedContent]
```

then remove the (now) redundant list comprehension:

```hs
sequence $ map beautyPrint splittedContent
```

The IDE, if you correctly set it up, should help you see that this can be further simplified:

```hs
mapM_ beautyPrint splittedContent
```